# pageSize bug in yii grid when using joins

Tags: php, yii

I have this search using joins. The results are correct but yii grid does not show all of the results even if the pagesize selected is greater than number of result.

here's my code :

```
        if($_GET['BaseIar']['description'] !='empty'){
            $criteria->with = array('class','classSi',);
            $this->description=$_GET['BaseIar']['description'];
            $criteria->compare('class.description', $this->description, true);
            $criteria->compare('classSi.description', $this->description, true, 'OR');
        }
```

here are the relations:

```
public function relations() {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.      
    return array( 
        'class' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'BaseEiEquipItem', 'iar_no'),
        'classSi' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'BaseSiReceivedItem','iar_no'),
    ); 
}
```

here's the grid:

```
  $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'base-iar-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$searchModel->search(),
    'columns'=>array(       
        array(
            'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'id'=>'base-iar-id',        
            'selectableRows'=>2, // multiple rows can be selected       
        ),                  
        'iar_id',   
        'dateInspected',
        array( 
        'name'=>'inspectedBy', 
        'value'=>'(!empty($data->inspectedBy))?$data->inspectedBy0->person->lastName.", ".$data->inspectedBy0->person->firstName." ".$data->inspectedBy0->person->middleName:"---"',
        ),

        array(
        'name'=>'endUser',
        'value'=>'(!empty($data->endUser))?$data->endUser0->person->lastName.", ".$data->endUser0->person->firstName." ".$data->endUser0->person->middleName:"---"',
        ),
        'dateReceived',
        array(
        'name'=>'receivedBy',
        'value'=>'(!empty($data->receivedBy))?$data->receivedBy0->person->lastName.", ".$data->receivedBy0->person->firstName." ".$data->receivedBy0->person->middleName:"---"',
        ),
        array(
        'name'=>'requisitionOffice',
        'value'=>'(!empty($data->requisitionOffice))?$data->requisitionOffice0->code:"---"',
        'value'=>'$data->requisitionOffice0->code'
        ),
        'prNo',
        'poNo',

        array(
            'class'=>'InfosysButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{view}',
            'afterDelete'=>'function(link,success,data){
                if(success){
                    jSuccess("Delete completed successfully!");                         
                }
            }',
            'buttons'=>array(
                'view' => array(
                    'label' => 'View details',
                    'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("pims/IAR/BaseIar/view", array("id"=>$data["id"]))'
                        ),
            ),              
            'header'=>CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'pageSize',array('10'=>'10','20'=>'20','30'=>'30','50'=>'50','100'=>'100','ALL'=>'All'),array('onchange'=>'$.fn.yiiGridView.update("base-iar-grid", {data:{pageSize:$(this).val()}});')),
        ),
    )
));
```

What might be the correct way to declare multiple relations in $criteria->with?

Comment: What's this `!= 'empty'` ? Are you sure that's correct? Shouldn't you be using something like `isset()` to check whether there's data in `$_GET` ?

Comment: 'empty' is a string value I used as description..@FelipeAlmeida

Comment: Show, please, code of using widget (CGridView or CListView, which you're using)

Comment: please see revision @CreatoR

Answer (score 0):

Hey I found this piece of example code in [the docs for with()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#with-detail), maybe it'll help you:

```
Post::model()->with(array(
    'author'=>array('select'=>'id, name'),
    'comments'=>array('condition'=>'approved=1', 'order'=>'create_time'),
))->findAll();
```